# Dynamic model creation for JSON parsing using GSON in java

Tags: java, json, gson

To parse the response from SOAP services I am using `GSON`. Currently I am having individual model classes for each service. There are tow services which are almost similar in response.

1. Response from Service 1

> {
>
> ```
>    "settings":[
>       {
>          "type":"userPreferences",
>          "enforced":false,
>          "name":"SavedItems",
>          "private":false,
>          "value":{
>             "type":"xs:string",
>             "$":"sessionExpired"
>          },
>          "canWrite":true,
>          "displayName":"Saved Items"
>       }
>    ]
> }
> ```

1. Response from Service 2

> {
>
> ```
>    "settings":[
>       {
>          "type":"selectMultipleItems",
>          "enforced":true,
>          "name":"cartInfo",
>          "private":true,
>          "value":{
>             "type":"xs:string",
>             "$":"currentPage"
>          },
>          "lookupValue": "Profile,Home,Transaction,Error",
>          "canWrite":true,
>          "displayName":"Current Page Index"
>       }
>    ]
> }
> ```

Clearly visible there is one more filed i.e. lookupValue in the response from service 2.

I am having two questions here, which are listed below-

1. Is the any way to handle this condition in a common model class rather than having individual model classes for each one?
2. JSON is key value pair structure, can i create such class which can dynamically allocate each key mapped with its value? This will work for any JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - You are not forced to provide each fields of the destination Object in your JSon. That means you can create an object with a `lookupValue` field, and use that same object for both Json above. The field will simply be ignored (null) in the first one.

2 - that's more or less what's Gson does internally. Try this :

```
public class Test {
  String x;
  Integer y;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Object.class, new JsonDeserializer<Object>() {
      @Override
      public Object deserialize(JsonElement arg0, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
        Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> values = arg0.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
        System.out.println(values);

        return null;
      }

    }).create();

    gson.fromJson("{'x':'AA','y':5}", Test.class);
  }
}
```

As you see in the adapter, you can retrieve `Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>>` which provide you the name (in the Json) of a field and the associated value.

Comment: Hi Pom, thanks for the wonderful answer. I got the first point. I am having a question with second point. My question is "Is it possible to have a model class, which can work for any JSON?" In the above solution, can you tell me if i send some JSON, how can i get any value from it?

Comment: Gson and Jackson work by reflection, matching class' fields with Json's ones. Thus that's not possible to get a class that work for any Json. The only way is to do the mapping yourself (for instance, from the entry set of the code sample).